# activated print preview in google chrome but can't see any preview

Tags: google-chrome, print-preview

Is the built-in print preview in chrome 10 supposed to look this way:

[image]

I enabled it by going to chrome://flags, and restarted chrome. But all I see is a wide grey preview which is not even close to the preview I wan't to see.
What do I do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience the same issue on both my Windows and Linux systems.  It seems the feature hasn't been fully implemented yet.

Remember, the disclaimer at the top of the `about:flags` page reads:

> **Careful, these experiments may bite**
>
> **WARNING** These experimental features may change, break, or disappear at any time. We make absolutely no guarantees about what may happen if you turn one of these experiments on, and your browser may even spontaneously combust. Jokes aside, your browser may delete all your data, or your security and privacy could be compromised in unexpected ways. Please proceed with caution.

Just feel lucky your browser didn't *spontaneously combust*! :-)

Comment: That’s silly. Why provide an option to expose a function that doesn’t even exist? Beta (or even alpha) software is supposed to at least exist and be functional, if potentially buggy. `:roll:`

Answer (score 1):

There's now a working Print Preview feature starting with Google Chrome 12.0.733.0, except the Print button from the Print Preview feature of Chrome is not yet functional.

Just wait for the final release of Chrome 12 to get a "working" Print Preview feature.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome on the dev channel has been recently updated to version 12.0.742.0.
Print Preview in this new build has a slightly new user interface BUT the Print button from the Print Preview tab NOW works as expected.

Again, wait for Google Chrome 12.0 to reach final in order to get its own Print Preview feature.

Answer (score 0):

This feature only works in the developer version of Chrome, not the release version.  Not sure if Print Preview will be finished up for Chrome 11, but it is being worked on.  Compared to Firefox's Print Preview, I'm not very impressed so far.  It will be a shame if Google doesn't get more horsepower behind this broadly requested tool.